# Pipe() - read-end in parent process stays empty

Tags: c++, ubuntu, pipe, fork, posix

This question follows from my attempts to implement 
http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html
and
https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

I'm writing a shell program; the intention is that, eventually, it can execute commands and pipe them to another program. As such, I require the stdout of a child process directly, rather than outputting to terminal. I attempted to use the above guides, but I have a problem: The pipe is always empty. It just doesn't work. I have absolutely no clue why. Here's my code:

```
int pipefd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    char buf;
    const char* arg = "/bin/ls";
    char *args[] = {"/bin/ls", (char *) 0};
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pid<0) {
        std::cout << "Fork() failed!." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid == 0) {  //According to everything I could find on the internet, pipe should work.
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // It does not. I don't know why.
        close(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execv(arg, args);
        std::cout << "Child Error! " << errno << std::endl;
        perror("execv");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        wait(NULL);
        while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0){
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        close(pipefd[0]);
    }
```

I'm on a laptop with Ubuntu 15.04
Also, the pipe DOES work if I write/read inside one process.
Edit: Also, the execv does work - If I remove the dup2, it outputs directly to terminal and works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Start with improving you question's title.

Comment: You are creating separate pipes in the parent and child.  Create the pipe before forking the child.